# Using exec()/compile() with user input

Tags: python, function, input

If I were to use `compile()` and `exec()` to execute some code that the user inputed, can functions or variables defined in the code be used again outside?
For example:

```
code = ""
while 1:
    line = input("")
    if line == "":
        break
    code += line

exec(compile(code, "code", "exec"))
print(test()+1)
```

This will not return `6` like I would expect. It gives a `NameError` but there is no problem with compiling or executing the code. There is no error if code is just a string and not input. Is there any way to use the function `test()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable name resolution and scoping are done at compilation time, so if a variable/function name is defined at run time with `exec`, you would need to use the `locals()` dict to reference it instead:

```
exec(compile(code, "code", "exec"))
print(locals()['test']()+1)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, is there any way to use variables/functions from my code in the input?

Comment: Yes, you can call it with `globals()` and `locals()` passed to it: `exec(compile(code, "code", "exec"), globals(), locals())`